# How to pre-populate lightning:select field?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningselect

I'm a new developer and would appreciate any help with this question.

I am trying to pre-populate a lightning:select field based on a variable in the URL.

I am able to dynamically generate the list of options for the field, but I can't seem to get it to populate with the variable from the URL.

I am using a wrapper class to get both the list of options and my chosen option in the same call - class adapated from here: http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/06/use-wrapper-class-lightning-component/

Here is my code:

Lightning Component:

```
    <aura:attribute name="variableURL"            type="String" default="Nothing"/>
    <aura:attribute name="srvList"                type="Object"/> 

    <aura:handler name="init"    value="{!this}"   action="{!c.onInit}" /> 

    <fieldset class="slds-box slds-m-top_small ">
        <legend class="slds-text-heading_medium">Provide us with some extra details</legend>

        <div class="slds-form-element__row">
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-size__2-of-2 slds-medium-size__1-of-2">
                <lightning:select aura:id="formField" name="formField" label="Service Area" required="true" value="{!v.variableURL}">
                    <option value="">- Not Specified -</option>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.srvList.lstServices}" var="ans">
                        <option value="{!ans.Name}" text="{!ans.Name}" selected="{!ans.Name == v.srvList.selectServ.Name}"></option>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>                             
            </div>
        </div> 


    </fieldset>

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    onInit : function(component, event, helper) {

       var action = component.get("c.initMethod");
       var variableURL = component.get("v.variableURL");

       action.setParams({
           variableURL : variableURL
       });

       action.setCallback(this, function(a) {

         var state = a.getState();
         console.log("state: ",state);

         if (state === 'SUCCESS'){

             //set response value in wrapperList attribute on component.
             var response = a.getReturnValue();
             console.log("response: ",response);


             component.set("v.srvList",response);

            }

       });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }

})
```

Apex Class:

```
public class SADC_Contact_Us {

       @AuraEnabled
           public static wrapperClass initMethod(String variableURL){
             //create a wrapper class object and set the wrapper class @AuraEnabled properties and return it to the lightning component.
               wrapperClass returnwrapperClass = new  wrapperClass ();        
               returnwrapperClass.lstServices = [SELECT Name from Website_Service__c WHERE Service_Level__c =1 LIMIT 25];
                returnwrapperClass.selectServ = [SELECT Name from Website_Service__c WHERE Service_Level__c =1 AND Name=:variableURL LIMIT 1];
              return returnwrapperClass;    
    }

       //wrapper or Inner class with @AuraEnabled {get;set;} properties*    
        public class wrapperClass{
                @AuraEnabled public List<Website_Service__c> lstServices{get;set;}
                @AuraEnabled public List<Website_Service__c> selectServ {get;set;}
        }    
}
```

So the aura:iteration on items="{!v.srvList.lstServices}" works fine, but this part does not load anything:

```
selected="{!ans.Name == v.srvList.selectServ.Name}
```

Can anyone advise how to get this selected part working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are assigning `List<Website_Service__c>` to **selectServ** and when you try to get value on it like `selectServ.Name`, it will be undefined. You should rather get it from a particular record. I see that you are are fetching single element **LIMIT 1**. You can use below:

```
selected="{!ans.Name == v.srvList.selectServ[0].Name}
```

This will fetch the `Name` of 1st element (0th index).

Comment: That did the trick - thanks!

Comment: If its solved, pls mark the question closed. You can check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work